# Is it 'election account', 'electoral account', or 'campaign account'?

Tags: word-request

What do you call an official banking account for expenditures incurred due to the person's election campaign (buying TV ads, printing campaign materials, transportation costs, etc.)? Google News doesn't give a significant number of results for both 'election account' and 'electoral account'. (by the way, what is the difference between 'election' and 'electoral' when it's used as a modifier? you can refrain from answering this additional question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the term is: campaign bank account

> Prior to opening a **campaign bank accoun**t, you may need to establish a
>   political campaign committee with your local county Board of
>   Elections. The name you use for your campaign committee is the name
>   you will use to open the bank account. The bank will require committee
>   paperwork along with personal identification.

[campaign bank account](https://www.onlinecandidate.com/articles/opening-bank-account-political-campaign)

> Open a **Campaign Bank Account**
>
> Candidates for statewide, district or
>   county office, Governor's Council, and mayor or city council in
>   Boston, Brockton, Cambridge, Fall River, Lawrence, Lowell, Lynn, New
>   Bedford, Newton, Quincy, Sommerville, Springfield and Worcester must
>   conduct their campaign finance activity through a depository bank
>   account, with their financial institutions filing regular reports with
>   OCPF. All other candidates are legally required to segregate their
>   campaign funds from their personal funds. While a bank account is not
>   explicitly required by the campaign finance law, candidates and
>   committees are advised to open a checking account to conduct campaign
>   activity. To open a bank account, you will need an Employer
>   Identification Number (EIN).

[campaign bank account](https://www.ocpf.us/Home/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)

These accounts are for funds raised for an election.

Electoral is an adjective, election is the noun.

Candidates for election are electoral candidates.

Answer (score 0):

Typically these are called "**campaign funds**."

See these recent (slightly paraphrased) headlines:

CNN - [Congressman to resign after guilty plea over **misusing campaign funds**](https://www.cnn.com/2019/12/06/politics/duncan-hunter-to-resign/index.html)

Yahoo Finance - [Where do **campaign funds** go when candidates drop out?](https://finance.yahoo.com/video/where-campaign-funds-candidates-drop-191952316.html)

Reuters - [Boris Johnson's Conservatives raise record UK **campaign funds**](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-britain-election-fundraising/boris-johnsons-conservatives-raise-record-uk-campaign-funds-idUSKBN1Y21RT)

[Here](https://ethics.house.gov/campaign-activity/proper-use-campaign-funds-and-resources) is a list from the U.S. House Ethics Committee of "Proper Use of **Campaign Funds** and Resources"

Broad discussions about political fundraising generally refer to "campaign finance" or "campaign financing."

Comment: campaign funds are deposited in a campaign bank account

Comment: 'Campaign funds' means "campaign money"